# Codeigniter pdf file password not working Google Drive

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

I am creating codeigniter pdf file download with password, using mpdf library. pdf file upload and view using password not working google drive. how to resolve, help me.

**Library**

```
    <?php

if(!defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed');

class m_pdf {
    #code
    function m_pdf(){
        $CI = & get_instance();
        log_message('Debug', 'mPDF class is loaded');
    }

    function load($param=NULL){
        include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';

        if($params == NULL){
            $param = '"en-GB-x", "A4", "", "", 10,10,10,10,6,3';
        }

        return new mPDF($param);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{

    $this->load->library('m_pdf');

    $pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();

    $data = [];

    $passWord = 'test123';
    //password generate PDF

    $pdf->SetProtection(array(), $passWord);
    //$data['the_content']='mPDF and CodeIgniter are cool!';

    $html = $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data, true);

    $pdfFilePath = 'pdf_output.pdf';

    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);

    //print_r($pdf);

    $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");

    return $pdfFilePath;


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in mPDF - see respective mPDF Github issues

- [FYI: Gmail In-Browser Document Viewer won't open Encrypted PDFs generated with mPDF #171](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/171)
- [PDF opening without password when using Finder on Mac #181](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/181)

You can:

- either password-protect the file using an external tool,
- use en external tool entirely (TCPDF handles encryption correctly),
- or wait until the issue is resolved in mPDF which can take a substantial time.